# Copy Files with exact Structure into another Directory using XCopy

Tags: windows, file, copy, xcopy

Think I want to copy this file `C:\Majid\File\text.txt` to `D:\Copied` (`C:\Majid\File\text.txt ---> D:\Copied`)

I want to use Xcopy to copy that file with its full directory into `D:\Copied`, then I should have something like this ---> `D:\Copied\Majid\File\text.txt` , as you see the drive letter is removed and all of other directory is created in destination directory.

How can I do this action by XCopy?

Comment: are you planning to execute this command manually from the console or from a program you made yourself? Which language? If manually execution this does not belong here in SO!

Comment: I disagree Davide, I think this is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
set sourceFolder="C:\Users\User\Desktop\34\*"
set destinationFolder=%sourceFolder:~3,-1%

xcopy %sourceFolder%  "D:\xcopied%destinationFolder%" /s /i /r
```

based on @daniel and @WahidBitar answers. Thank you men ;)

Answer (score 1):

see this:

[XCOPY COMMAND](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)

...
Syntax
xcopy Source [Destination] [/w] [/p] [/c] [/v] [/q] [/f] [/l] [/g] [/d[:mm-dd-yyyy]] [/u] [/i] [/s [/e]] [/t] [/k] [/r] [/h] [{/a|/m}] [/n] [/o] [/x] [/exclude:file1[+[file2]][+[file3]] [{/y|/-y}] [/z]
...

what you will find interesting in that page is this:

**/s** : Copies directories and subdirectories, unless they are empty. If you omit **/s, xcopy** works within a single directory.

Comment: Hi Davide, I have an application which monitors a directory for new files, after that you can execute an application for those files, I want to use Xcopy for it. /s command will not work. Imagine my file is C:\Majid\Text.txt, If I use /s it only copy text.txt and won' create Majid folder on destination folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
set sourceFolder="C:\test\new folder\text.txt"
set destinationFolder=%sourceFolder:~3,-1%
echo %destinationFolder%

xcopy %sourceFolder%  "D:\xcopied%destinationFolder%"
```

Something like that could work. Remove the first few characters of the source ("C:"), then add the characters for the destination folder ("D:\xcopied").

Comment: Hi daniel, Nice Answer, But it will ask a question while executing.It will ask the target directory is a file name or directory, and I should enter F or D. I do not want to se this message and set its default option to D. How to that Daniel? Thanks For your Nice answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

this one was good for me

```
xcopy $(SolutionDir)Libs\YourFolder\* $(TargetDir)YourFolder /s /i /r
```

[source](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
("XCOPY.EXE", "/E /I /Y " + filename + " " 
+ pfadauswahl + "Backup\\" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
+ "\\UserData\\" + File_Name + "* ");
```

with the star at the end of the line, i got rid of the question if its either a file or a dir.. since you didn't specify anything on how you want to use it... here is the solution for c#

Comment: The question is about XCopy from the command line. It asks nothing about C# or `Process.Start`, and your answer is full of variables and function calls that mean nothing from the command line. I'm not sure how this is supposed to answer the question asked here.