# how to copy multiple files to a folder using xcopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

would you please let me kno how can I copy multiple directories located in different locations to a backup directoy

sources(directories)  are D:\share\t1 , D:\new\t3 , C:\media\t4  F:\save\bank
destination directory  is C:\shared\backup

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Files with Their Folder into another Directory using XCopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304359/copy-files-with-their-folder-into-another-directory-using-xcopy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not a `for` loop? I love it and it is the best fit for this arcane question:

```
 For %%a in (
 "D:\share\t1"
 "D:\new\t3"
 "C:\media\t4"
 "F:\save\bank"
  ) do (
xcopy /s /d "%%~a" "c:\shared\backup"
  )
```

Comment: If you enclose the paths in double quotes and use "%%~a" then this allows the user to use long pathname elements as well as short pathnames.

Comment: Thank a million, this for loop works perfect , only one small issue that I'm sure can be fixed by using another option but I'm not expert as you

Comment: What "small issue" , please explain.

Comment: sorry for clicking enter mistakenly , Thank a million, this for loop works perfect , only one small issue that I'm sure can be fixed by using another option but I'm not expert as you . this loop copies over all "files" which are under those 4 directories to destination  I want to copy over t1 directory and all content underneath of it , thanks again

Comment: @Endoro
Thank a million, this for loop works perfect , only one small issue that I'm sure can be fixed by using another option but I'm not expert as you . this loop copies over all "files" which are under those 4 directories to destination I want to copy over t1 directory and all content underneath of it , thanks again –

Comment: You mean: copy `D:\share\t1`  with subfolders, all other without subfolders?

Comment: no , I need to copy D:\share\t1 with subfolders , files (eveything under it  + copy D:\new\t3 with subfolders and files + 
 copy C:\media\t4 with subfolders and files + 
copy F:\save\bank with subfolders and files  , I just did some search for options to use with xcopy, I believ /e shall do the job ,but it doesn't .  xcopy /s /d /e "%%~a" "c:\shared\backup" copies over the subfolders and files under t1 but not "t1" itself (t1 is just an example, i want copy over all 4 in same fashion)

Comment: if I give the command `xcopy /s /d "d:\share\t1" "c:\shared\backup"`it copies all files **in t1** _and_ all files **in all subfolders** of t1 to "c:\shared\backup". I tested it here.

Comment: @Endoro if i give xcopy  /d /s /e /i /h /r "d:\share\t1" "c:\shared\backup\t1 then it works for one copy but dont know how to use it in your loop to pick "t1" (folder name) from source to create the same structure in destination

Comment: If you use the option `/d` only older files will be overwritten by newer ones, see `help xcopy`  on the command line. And with my Windows version (XP) the folder `t1` was created sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to do this.

Try:

```
 For %%a in (D:\share\t1,D:\new\t3,C:\media\t4,F:\save\bank) do xcopy %%a c:\shared\backup
```

Comment: No, you don't. This  is a hard-coded list of folder names. There's no advantage (or *need*) for a loop; you can achieve the same thing g with r separate lines, and make it easier to read and maintain. The loop is only necessary if the content is variable.

Comment: @Ken White - you're right. I think this is plenty easy to read but I write a lot of batch files. I updated my answer.